# Chordal graph question

Tags: graphs

In the below image, the graph is being triangulated (added edges are in red). My question is simple :
**Is the red edge between nodes 7 and 10 necessary in order to obtain a chordal graph?**

[image]

(this image comes from Yaroslav Bulatov's excellent answer on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/the-origin-of-the-notion-of-treewidth/5020#5020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not necessary.

Let $G$ be the graph made by deleting the edge $\{7,10\}$ from the graph in the question.  Any cycle in $G$ that includes $7$ and $10$ must include both $6$ and $8$, because such a cycle must be the union of two disjoint $7$–$10$ paths, and $\{6,8\}$ is a cut that separates $7$ from $10$.  However, $\{6,8\}$ is an edge, so any cycle in $G$ that includes $7$ and $10$ already has $\{6,8\}$ as a chord, so it doesn't need $\{7,10\}$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can delete that edge and the graph remains chordal. This is so because you don't introduce an induced cycle of length 4 or more.